# SnowflakeUtil.generate(A_NUMBER) returns type String

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

i logged typeof SnowflakeUtil.generate(A_NUMBER) and it returns a string? it says snowflake at the docs

Comment: A snowflake is a string: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake

Comment: but how come i get a error when i attempt to


member.roles.add(member.guild.roles.fetch(SnowflakeUtil.generate(MY_ROLE_ID) it gives me a TypeError?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use this for your usecase.

I saw your comment

you can just do `member.roles.add("YOUR_ROLE_ID")`